# PHP - JSON Array - Unsure how to extract data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following JSON/Array from AWS and I'm struggling to read it with PHP:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "666483cb-e012-51f2-8d66-d308d55efd98",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:848283244672:S-Notification-Queue",
  "Message" : "{\"notificationType\":\"Delivery\",\"mail\"}"
}
```

Essentially I need to access the "Message" part of the array and be able to use the value pairs within like "notificationType = Delivery".

I've tried looping through the array with a PHP foreach look and I've tried decoding the array as follows:

```
$message_data = json_decode($message,true);
```

however I'm still struggling to access the data within. Note: I have the data in a variable $message.

Any advice on how to access the message data?

Also hoping to access parts within the Message section like:

```
{\"name\":\"Subject\",\"value\":\"abc"}
```

www.singles.dating

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message section of that JSON is itself a string of JSON, so after decoding the whole JSON object you will need to decode the message property again. Assuming that JSON is in a variable called `$aws_notification`, you can do this:

```
$message_json = json_decode( $aws_notification, true )[ 'Message' ];
$message_data = json_decode( $message_json, true );
```

Then use can access `$message_data[ 'notificationType' ]` and its other properties.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Message` is serialized json.

So it needs decoding also

```
$message_data = json_decode($message, true);
if(
  isset($message_data['Message']) AND !is_array($message_data['Message'])
) {
  $message_data['Message'] = json_decode($message_data['Message'], true);
}
```